# Event 'Load' cannot be found

Tags: vb.net

Getting the error "Event 'Load' cannot be found" referring to "Handles MyBase.Load"  Please see attached code.  Any help much appreciated!

I have many other applications set up the same way and they all work.  However, these were in an older version of Visual Studio.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System, System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub cleanXMLDialog_Load(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal 
  eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Main()
        End
    End Sub

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim directories() As String = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\")
        Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles("C:\", "*.dll")
        DirSearch("c:\")
    End Sub

    Sub DirSearch(ByVal sDir As String)
        Dim d As String
        Dim f As String
        Try
            For Each d In Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)
                For Each f In Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.xml")
                    'Dim Response As String = MsgBox(f)
                    Debug.Write(f)
                Next
                DirSearch(d)
            Next
        Catch excpt As System.Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(excpt.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Load should happen without this error.

Comment: I don't know VB.NET very well so I could be off track here, but your class Form1 isn't inheriting from anything.  So, what does "MyBase" refer to?   Should Form1 not derive from the base Windows Form class?   Based on the documentation, MyBase is a VB.NET construct that refers to the instances base class...in this case, you haven't provided one as far as I can tell.

Comment: Here is the doc that I was referring to:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/me-my-mybase-and-myclass

Comment: If you do this without using the Winforms project template then you need to declare the form class correctly.  Add `Inherits Form`.  Do note that the form does nothing useful, consider Project > Properties > Application tab, "Startup Form" = Sub Main.

Comment: @user1011627 In a WinForms project the Partial Class Form1 found in the designed code shows the proper inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the class declaration:

```
Public Class Form1
```

It looks like you intend this to inherit from a windows [`Form`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=netframework-4.7.2) type, but there's nothing here to make that happen.

You may want this:

```
Public Class Form1 Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

but even this is unlikely to really accomplish anything. It's not enough just to inherit from the `Form` type if you don't have any controls are properties set and don't ever show the form.

Did you accidentally create a **Console** or **Class Library** project when you mean to create a **WinForms** project?

Comment: This is a Windows Application project, not one of the other two.  Only clue so far,  I got the project running under Visual Studio 2008 but not Visual Studio 2017.  So able to proceed but would like to start using VS 2017 asap for this project.